# Using bzip2 low-level routines to compress chunks of data

Tags: c, compression, bzip2

**The Overview**

I am using the low-level calls in the `libbzip2` library:  `BZ2_bzCompressInit()`, `BZ2_bzCompress()` and `BZ2_bzCompressEnd()` to compress chunks of data to standard output.

I am migrating working code from higher-level calls, because I have a stream of bytes coming in and I want to compress those bytes in *sets* of discrete chunks (a *discrete chunk* is a set of bytes that contains a group of tokens of interest — my input is logically divided into groups of these chunks).

A complete group of chunks might contain, say, 500 chunks, which I want to compress to one bzip2 stream and write to standard output.

Within a set, using the pseudocode I outline below, if my example buffer is able to hold 101 chunks at a time, I would open a new stream, compress 500 chunks in runs of 101, 101, 101, 101, and one final run of 96 chunks that closes the stream.

**The Problem**

The issue is that my `bz_stream` structure instance, which keeps tracks of the number of compressed bytes in a single pass of the `BZ2_bzCompress()` routine, seems to claim to be writing more compressed bytes than the total bytes in the final, compressed file.

For example, the compressed output could be a file with a true size of 1234 bytes, while the number of reported compressed bytes (which I track while debugging) is somewhat higher than 1234 bytes (say 2345 bytes).

My rough pseudocode is in two parts.

The first part is a rough sketch of what I do to compress a subset of chunks (and I know that I have another subset coming after this one):

```
bz_stream bzStream;
unsigned char bzBuffer[BZIP2_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH] = {0};
unsigned long bzBytesWritten = 0UL;
unsigned long long cumulativeBytesWritten = 0ULL;
unsigned char myBuffer[UNCOMPRESSED_MAX_LENGTH] = {0};
size_t myBufferLength = 0;

/* initialize bzStream */
bzStream.next_in = NULL;
bzStream.avail_in = 0U;
bzStream.avail_out = 0U;
bzStream.bzalloc = NULL;
bzStream.bzfree = NULL;
bzStream.opaque = NULL;
int bzError = BZ2_bzCompressInit(&bzStream, 9, 0, 0); 

/* bzError checking... */

do
{
    /* read some bytes into myBuffer... */

    /* compress bytes in myBuffer */
    bzStream.next_in = myBuffer;
    bzStream.avail_in = myBufferLength;
    bzStream.next_out = bzBuffer;
    bzStream.avail_out = BZIP2_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH;
    do 
    {
        bzStream.next_out = bzBuffer;
        bzStream.avail_out = BZIP2_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH;
        bzError = BZ2_bzCompress(&bzStream, BZ_RUN);

        /* error checking... */

        bzBytesWritten = ((unsigned long) bzStream.total_out_hi32 << 32) + bzStream.total_out_lo32;
        cumulativeBytesWritten += bzBytesWritten;

        /* write compressed data in bzBuffer to standard output */
        fwrite(bzBuffer, 1, bzBytesWritten, stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
    } 
    while (bzError == BZ_OK);
} 
while (/* while there is a non-final myBuffer full of discrete chunks left to compress... */);
```

Now we wrap up the output:

```
/* read in the final batch of bytes into myBuffer (with a total byte size of `myBufferLength`... */

/* compress remaining myBufferLength bytes in myBuffer */
bzStream.next_in = myBuffer;
bzStream.avail_in = myBufferLength;
bzStream.next_out = bzBuffer;
bzStream.avail_out = BZIP2_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH;
do 
{
    bzStream.next_out = bzBuffer;
    bzStream.avail_out = BZIP2_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH;
    bzError = BZ2_bzCompress(&bzStream, (bzStream.avail_in) ? BZ_RUN : BZ_FINISH);

    /* bzError error checking... */

    /* increment cumulativeBytesWritten by `bz_stream` struct `total_out_*` members */
    bzBytesWritten = ((unsigned long) bzStream.total_out_hi32 << 32) + bzStream.total_out_lo32;
    cumulativeBytesWritten += bzBytesWritten;

    /* write compressed data in bzBuffer to standard output */
    fwrite(bzBuffer, 1, bzBytesWritten, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
} 
while (bzError != BZ_STREAM_END);

/* close stream */
bzError = BZ2_bzCompressEnd(&bzStream);

/* bzError checking... */
```

**The Questions**

- Am I calculating `cumulativeBytesWritten` (or, specifically, `bzBytesWritten`) incorrectly, and how would I fix that?

I have been tracking these values in a debug build, and I do not seem to be "double counting" the `bzBytesWritten` value. This value is counted and used once to increment `cumulativeBytesWritten` after each successful `BZ2_bzCompress()` pass.

- Alternatively, am I not understanding the correct use of the `bz_stream` state flags?

For example, does the following compress and keep the bzip2 stream open, so long as I keep sending some bytes?

```
bzError = BZ2_bzCompress(&bzStream, BZ_RUN);
```

Likewise, can the following statement compress data, so long as there are at least some bytes are available to access from the `bzStream.next_in` pointer (`BZ_RUN`), and then the stream is wrapped up when there are no more bytes available (`BZ_FINISH`)?

```
bzError = BZ2_bzCompress(&bzStream, (bzStream.avail_in) ? BZ_RUN : BZ_FINISH);
```

- Or, am I not using these low-level calls correctly at all? Should I go back to using the higher-level calls to continuously append a grouping of compressed chunks of data to one main file?

There's probably a simple solution to this, but I've been banging my head on the table for a couple days in the course of debugging what could be wrong, and I'm not making much progress. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to my own question, it appears I am miscalculating the number of bytes written. I should not use the `total_out_*` members. The following correction works properly:

```
bzBytesWritten = sizeof(bzBuffer) - bzStream.avail_out;
```

The rest of the calculations follow.